# flutter_facebook_login message type in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login

In Flutter 1 this was working fine but now in Flutter 2 it's not:

[image]

It's like it's missing the type for `e`. I tried adding `FirebaseAuthException e` but it needs to be an `Object`.

[image]

Comment: cast your "e" as FirebaseAuthException... every Object is an Object in Dart. You can do: final error = e as FirebaseAuthException;

Comment: ok so basically I need to declare a new error var before the check. It works. Post an answer with that if you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is kinda tricky with the exceptions, you can do as following:

```
final error = e as FirebaseAuthException;
```

and that will do the trick. You can also do a "if" statement like:

```
if (error is FirebaseAuthException) {
    print(error.message);
}
```

and that will work as well;